# AJAX getting onChange to work

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have set up a form where the user can comment by entering their name, email and comment.

I want to run a validation on the input once the user leaves the *#name* field, but I can't get it to work please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#name').on("change", function () {

    var name = $('input[name=name]');

    if (name.val()=='') { //A regex check will be added later on to check for invalid caracters
        name.addClass('hightlight');
        $('#name_error').show();
        var error = true;
    } else {
        name.removeClass('hightlight');
        $('#name_error').hide();
    }

    if ($(error).length) {
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it to trigger on leave than you can use:

```
$('#name').blur(function() {
//your code

}
```

Refer here: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

if you want to trigger on change than:

```
$('#name').change(function() {
//your code

}
```

Refer here:http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#name').focusout(function() {
    //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use focusout instead of change

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#name').focusout(function () {
            var name = $('input[name=name]');
            if (name.val() == '') { //A regex check will be added later on to check for invalid caracters
                name.addClass('hightlight');
                $('#name_error').show();
                var error = true;
            } else {
                name.removeClass('hightlight');
                $('#name_error').hide();
            }

            if ($(error).length) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```